# Is there a function in haskell to determine if each element in a list is in another list?

Tags: haskell

I am wondering if there is a function in haskell to determine if each element in a list is in another list. I wrote my own, but it seems like something that would be in `Prelude` or `Data.List`

```
each :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> Bool
each xs ys = foldl (\acc x -> if x `elem` ys then True && acc else False) True xs
```

Does something like this already exist?

Comment: If the lists are large and performance matters, you may want to switch to a different data structure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The set operation you want specifically is not in the Prelude, but `all` makes the definition somewhat trivial (though not necessarily efficient).

```
-- Check if every element in xs is in ys (i.e., is xs a subset of ys)
each xs ys = all (`elem` ys) xs
```

Assuming your lists do not have duplicate values, you might try `(\\)`.

```
import Data.List

-- Check if removing all elements in ys from xs produces an empty list.
each xs ys = null (xs \\ ys)
```

Comment: I like the `(\\)/null` `each` function you showed above. I benchmarked it and it actually turned out to be a good bit faster than mine. Very cool. I'll just `nub xs` before `(\\)`ing it

Comment: You don't actually have to check against everything.`(\\)` produces the list lazily, and as soon as `null` sees *any* value, it can return `False`. For example, `null [1..]` returns `False` rather than hanging.